# Blur the screen yet keep it functional

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am looking for a way to blur the screen yet keep it functional. Preferably this should work for MacOS, Linux and Windows. I have been looking a bit into QT5. I managed to create a transparent overlay that clicks through (so it keeps the screen functional) but I am not sure I can achieve the blurring effect. Is possible using QT? And if so how? Do you have another possibly better way of getting this done?

My language of preference here would be python but of course this is not a limitation.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets

class mymainwindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowFlags(
            QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint |
            QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint |
            QtCore.Qt.X11BypassWindowManagerHint
            )
        self.setGeometry(QtWidgets.QStyle.alignedRect(
            QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter,
            QtCore.QSize(2200, 320),
            QtWidgets.qApp.desktop().availableGeometry()))

        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents, True)

        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
mywindow = mymainwindow()
mywindow.show()
app.exec_()
```